# 3D Object is not visible in real view in Swift

Tags: swift4, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to display a 3D drone object in through my camera. I have create ARSceneView and configure it properly and created a scene. I have also properly pass the object to that sceneView but when i run my app the object does not show any where, i have set its positioning also but still not getting the object anywhere. How can i see my object?My code to set scene and configuration is this,

```
func setupScene(){

    let scene = SCNScene()
    arView.scene = scene
}
func setupConfiguration(){

    let configure = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    arView.session.run(configure)

}
func addDrone() {
    drone.loadModel()
    arView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(drone)
}
```

This is my drone class for making the object as a childnode,

```
class Drone: SCNNode {
func loadModel() {
    guard let virtualObjectScene = SCNScene(named: "Drone.scn") else { return }
    let wrapperNode = SCNNode()
    for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
    }
    addChildNode(wrapperNode)
}
```

}

How can i get to see that?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it looks like your `Drone Class` never gets initialised.

If your SCNScene is in an `.scnassets` folder you also need to include that in your path.

Lets say therefore, that you have a folder named: ARAssets.scnassets

Your Drone Class should look like this:

```
class Drone: SCNNode{

override init() {

    super.init()

    guard let virtualObjectScene = SCNScene(named: "ARAssets.scnassets/Drone.scn") else { return }

    let wrapperNode = SCNNode()

    for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
    }
    self.addChildNode(wrapperNode)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

   }
}
```

And to actually load it you should do something like this in your viewController:

```
 func addDrone() {
    let droneNode = Drone()
    droneNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(droneNode)
}
```

You may also need to adjust the `scale` property of your Drone Node as well e.g

```
droneNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.01, 0.01. 0.01)
```

Comment: i have created a seperate group folder where i have placed my Drone.scn object. @Josh Robbins

Comment: it is still isn't showing through ur method. @Josh Robbins

Comment: The your path to the file is probably incorrect. I tried Wirth several models and it works fine :)

Comment: i'm following a tutorial in which he had done like this but still didn't shows that. @Josh Robbins

Comment: How can i give my folder path here? @Josh Robbins